# NullPointerException when i use @Secured in my RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am a beginner in Spring Security, so I coded a controller with two methods like this :

```
@RestController
public class EtudiantRestService {

    @Autowired
    private EtudiantReository etudiantReository;

    @Secured(value = {"ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_SCOLARITE"})
    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveEtudiant",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    private Etudiant saveEtudiant(Etudiant etudiant){
        System.out.println(etudiant.getNom());
        System.out.println(etudiant.getPrenom());
        return etudiantReository.save(etudiant);
    }

    @Secured(value = {"ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_SCOLARITE","ROLE_PROF","ROLE_ETUDIANT"})
    @RequestMapping(value = "/etudiants")
    public Page<Etudiant> listEtudiant(int page,int size){
        return etudiantReository.findAll(new PageRequest(page,size));
    }
}
```

The configurations of spring security is :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void globalConfig(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        // Type d'authentification (Base de données, LDAP, Mémoire)
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password("123456")
                .roles("ADMIN","PROF");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("prof").password("123456")
                .roles("PROF");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("etudiant1").password("123456")
                .roles("ETUDIANT");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("scolaritel").password("123456")
                .roles("SCOLARITE");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Pattern builder
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                        .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/index.html")
            .failureUrl("/error.html");
    }
}
```

Mon contrôleur fonctionne bien mais lorsque j'utilise la annotation @Secured et j'authentifier j'avais l'exception :

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.upsys.sec.service.EtudiantRestService.saveEtudiant(EtudiantRestService.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapt
    ....

Comment: Which is line 29 of your EtudiantRestService?

Comment: Doesn't look like a problem with @secure. Check if: 1. EtudiantRepository is properly autowired. 2. Method that deserializes `Etudiant` object from request body.

Comment: I'm sorry, i solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

It's just a mistake in the nomination of the `saveEtudiant` method, it's was `private`
I'm so sorry.